# Switching page when i try to update a data in Firebase DB- Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project in Ionic and firebase. The issue is, when i try to update a data in my DB, the view of the app is getting switched to another. Tried lot of work arounds, but not yet fixed. In the gif we can see the view is changing from property view to list view behing the ionic modal. Is there any one faced this issue before or have solution please help me to get this done. Thank You.[Error Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeOrd.gif)

This code snippet open the modal and update database:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/unitinfopopup.html', {
scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
 $scope.infomodal = modal;
});$scope.openinfoModal = function(pid) {

// Get a database reference to our posts
$scope.userd=PeopleLoginService.getPeople();

var reflogn = new Firebase("https://pspacedb.firebaseio.com/Users/"+$scope.userd.$id);
var authDatas = reflogn.getAuth();
$scope.ppointid="";
if (authDatas) {

  reflogn.on("value", function(snapshot) {

  $scope.ppointid=snapshot.val().ppoint;
  $scope.ppointid=$scope.ppointid-1;

  }, function (errorObject) {

  });
  if ($scope.ppointid>=1) {
    reflogn.update({ ppoint:$scope.ppointid});

    $scope.unitid='';

    var ref = new Firebase("https://pspacedb.firebaseio.com/Listing/"+pid);
    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    $scope.unitid=snapshot.val();
    }, function (errorObject) {

    });

    $scope.infomodal.show();
  }
  else {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'No Enough Credits!',
      template: 'You can buy credits from our store.'
    });
  }    
}
else {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
   title: 'Not LoggedIn!',
   template: 'Please Login to Show Profile.'
 });
}
```

};

HTML code:

```
<a class="tab-item" style="margin-top: 2.75%" type="button" ng-click="openinfoModal(properyid)"><i class="my-icon ion-information-circled"></i><p style="font-size: 13px">Unit Info</p></a>
```

Updating code:

```
reflogn.update({ ppoint:$scope.ppointid});
```

Comment: can you show some of the codes you have tried so far?

Comment: hi @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Updated the post, please have a look.

Comment: Anyone please help me..!